# iOS AutoLayout with scrollview and keyboard

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have one view on my storyboard to show user log in form, so it looks like this: main view->scroll view->content view->two text fields and log in button at the top and one register button at the bottom of the view. I use autolayout and bottom button has bottom space constraint. When I tap on the text field and keyboard appears I would like to scroll view to change size to visible rect, but content size should remain to scroll down to the register button, but the button move up when the size of the scroll view change. How could I do what I want?

I use this code when keyboard appears:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
    NSValue *kbFrame = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [kbFrame CGRectValue];

    CGSize s = self.scrollView.contentSize;
    CGFloat height = keyboardFrame.size.height;
    self.scrollViewBottomLayoutConstraint.constant = height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [self.scrollView setContentSize:s];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try leaving the content size alone, and instead adjust the scroll view's contentInset property. Then you don't have to mess with constraints.

```
- (void)keyboardUp:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];

    UIEdgeInsets contentInset = self.scrollView.contentInset;
    contentInset.bottom = keyboardRect.size.height;
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset;
}
```

Comment: nice and simple, but one problem is the scroll view bars don't resize to the visible part of the scroll/table/collection view.

Comment: Thank you. you save my time.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I have found is to override NSLayoutConstraint like so:

```
@implementation NHKeyboardLayoutConstraint

- (void) dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void) awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillChangeFrame:(NSNotification *)notification {

    CGRect endKBRect = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    CGFloat animationDuration = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];
    CGRect frame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.bounds;

    self.constant = frame.size.height - endKBRect.origin.y;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}


@end
```

then in your xib change the class type of the offending constraint to this class.

Comment: Thank you for this! I have spent days trying to use the usual solution that Bilobatum described and I've used before with success.Now I had a fairly complex layout that had to be constraint to the bottom and then the old 'trick' would not work.
Now I just replaced this constraint with this class and it worked!

I did a small addition:  
`float offset = 0; 
if (endKBRect.origin.y < frame.size.height)
  offset = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
self.constant = frame.size.height - endKBRect.origin.y - offset;`

To support no-homebutton phones.