# contentInset of the UIScrollView isn't working

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, swift, uiedgeinsets

I’m trying to move the content up when the keyboard appears. This is the content which is a simple login form.

[image]
[image]

Please note that these are not `UITextField`s. Its just a small `UITableView` in the middle of a `UIViewController`. And I have a `UIScrollView` filling the view controller embedding that table view.

I’ve registered for the keyboard notifications, `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`.

And in the method that fires when the keyboard appears, I've implemented a variation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19736900/1077789) answer which does pretty much the same thing, setting the `bottom` value of the `UIEdgeInsets` which is used to set the `contentInset` of the scroll view.

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {

    var info: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo as NSDictionary
    var keyboardSize: CGSize = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey).CGRectValue().size

    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

The problem is it doesn't do anything. I successfully get the height of the keyboard but nothing changes. Can anybody tell me why and what I should do to fix this please?

Thank you.

Comment: check this answer, it for ObjC, but the logic is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988866/how-do-i-resize-views-when-keyboard-pops-up-using-auto-layout/23992055#23992055

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much struggle, I was able to accomplish what I wanted. What I did was, in the `viewDidLoad` I registered for the keyboard notifications. And when the keyboard appears, I got its frame in to a variable and the login form's (which is a table view) frame into another variable.

By using `CGRectIntersection` I got the frame of the intersected portion when the keyboard overlaps the login form and go its height. Then I simply set it in scroll view's `setContentOffset` method to automatically move the scroll view up. To move it back down to the original position I just set scroll view's `contentOffset` property again to `CGPointZero`.

```
func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo as NSDictionary
    var keyboardFrame: CGRect = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey).CGRectValue()
    var loginFormFrame: CGRect = self.view.convertRect(self.tableView.frame, fromView: nil)
    var coveredFrame: CGRect = CGRectIntersection(loginFormFrame, keyboardFrame)

    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, coveredFrame.height + 20), animated: true)
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero
}
```

Comment: This code makes helpful self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero Thank you bro

Answer (score 2):

```
UIEdgeInsets UIEdgeInsetsMake (
   CGFloat top,
   CGFloat left,
   CGFloat bottom,
   CGFloat right
);
```

You are setting the bottom. Try setting the top insets. Maybe a negative value will help.

Comment: Setting a negative value to the top onset worked but I didn't want to hardcode values. That's why I was looking for a more cleaner method. I managed to do it by using a different method. I posted my answer here.

Answer (score -1):

`ContentInset` means The distance that the content view is inset from the enclosing scroll view. What you need to do is to change the origin.y value.

See [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Comment: the `contentInset` has been designed especially handling the appearing keyboards on the screen without changing the `UIScrollView` instance's `frame` – so there is nothing to do with the `frame` at all, you should have linked this one instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988866/how-do-i-resize-views-when-keyboard-pops-up-using-auto-layout/23992055#23992055

Comment: @Allen: I saw that thread before but the solutions there was of no use because I don't have any `UITextField`s in the view.

Comment: @holex I wanted to actually move up the scroll view automatically instead of enabling the user to scroll up. I managed to achieve this. I posted my answer here.